# embeddable java TCP proxy that supports delayed open (replacement for NetCrusher?)

Tags: java, tcp, proxy

We are currently using [Netcrusher](https://github.com/NetCrusherOrg/netcrusher-java/tree/master) to induce random "chaos monkey" TCP disconnects for testing purposes.  While this mostly works well, I am finding that it has a frustrating limitation that I have not figured out how to work around.  Our software uses the JMS client to access an HA pair of ActiveMQ Artemis services at `[host1:port1,host2:port2]`. We proxy these locally to `[localhost:30001,localhost:30002]`. However, the HA service pair operates with an active/backup mode, and only the active instance listens on its TCP port. Meanwhile, I want to make NetCrusher (or anything!) proxy these host:port pairs, but NetCrusher refuses to open the proxy to the not-yet-active service.  I really want it to just "keep trying to connect forever", or perhaps "try to connect only when something attempts the local connection to the proxy". Essentially I want the local proxy to faithfully reflect the state of the services. How can I do this?  I like NetCrusher, but I'll use whatever works.